# Marshalling error when caching models with date prior to 1900

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, marshalling

I have some active record models which have a "published_on" attribute.  When I attempt to cache models with a published_on date prior to 1/1/1900, I get an error such as:

```
Marshalling error for key 'popular_products': year too big to marshal: 1300 UTC
You are trying to cache a Ruby object which cannot be serialized to memcached.
```

I can reproduce a similar error with ruby:

```
irb(main)> Marshal.dump( Time.parse("1/1/1900") )
ArgumentError: year too big to marshal: 1899 UTC
```

What's the right approach for caching models with dates prior to 1900?

Comment: Hmm, what's you ruby version, it's working for me fine.  Output of that statement: `"\x04\bIu:\tTime\r%\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06:\voffseti\xFE\xB0\xB9"`

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_448/time.c#L4636-L4638 this is from latest version of 1.9.3 and this is from latest version of 2.0 https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_247/time.c#L4672-L4674

doesn't help you though apart from confirming on the limitation…

Comment: Ahhh, thanks @j03w - that confirms it.  The solution may be to use Date, rather than Time : 

    Marshal.dump( Date.parse("1/1/100") ) 

works just fine

Comment: @j03w if you want to make an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @j03w commented, this is a limitation of the Time type.  I chose to change the type to Date, which resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also overload the _dump and _load methods of Time class, as follow:

```
require 'time' # Time extension to have xmlschema method
class Time
  def _dump(level)
    xmlschema(9) # store nsec
  end
  def self._load(str)
    Time.parse(str)
  end
end

irb(main):013:0> t=Time.new(1515,1,1)
=> 1515-01-01 00:00:00 +0100
irb(main):014:0> a=Marshal.dump(t)
=> "\x04\bIu:\tTime(1515-01-01T00:00:00.000000000+01:00\x06:\x06ET"
irb(main):015:0> t==Marshal.load(a)
=> true
```

Comment: When I use your code, and run producation env, I get: "rails no time information in "K\x86\x1C\x80\x00\x00\xE0\x00"