# ArgumentError (year too big to marshal: 20 UTC)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the error that I get. In the trace log, I don't get any error in my code, just in rails core files.

```
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/time/marshal.rb:54:in `_dump'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/time/marshal.rb:54:in `_dump'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/session_store.rb:56:in `dump'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/session_store.rb:56:in `marshal'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/session_store.rb:150:in `marshal_data!'
```

According to the error, the view was rendered, so it seems that the problem is not in any of the records.

```
 Rendered reports/_results_debts.html.erb (11257.4ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 15791ms (Views: 6432.2ms | ActiveRecord: 6718.7ms)
```

I don't know where to start.
Can someone give an advice?

Using ruby 1.9.3

There is no column name of the model in the error description, so it is not like other questions that were asked here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marshalling error when caching models with date prior to 1900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247465/marshalling-error-when-caching-models-with-date-prior-to-1900)

Comment: No. it is not. As I described in my question, it seems that everything is OK with model, since I dont get any hint from rails that the model is involved. In the question that you refer to, the error is: "Marshalling error for key **'popular_products' **. Here there is no column name.

Comment: @NoamB.: in this case, are you trying to store invalid time in a session? Try cleaning cookies, the error should go away (provided that you won't be trying to set invalid time again)

Comment: Tried to. Now the error is different: Mysql has gone away. Any idea?

Comment: Restart the server. Connection is dead for some reason. Or mysql server is dead.

Comment: Error returned: ArgumentError (year too big to marshal: 17 UTC):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one of the records in our HUGE database, had a date column with the value of: 0020-12-31

Hurey!!!